# Trying to print first 5 perfect numbers using Euler's theorem

Tags: c++

Euler theorem states that this equation results into a perfect number if the right side (2^n -1) is a prime number.

2^(n-1) * (2^n -1)

My code is trying to generate the first 5 perfect numbers being : 6,28,496.8128 etc... However upon execution it simply prints the numbers of Euler's equation with different n values (1,2,3,4 etc..). It seems there is a mistake with my Prime condition. Can anyone help ?

So i get 6,28,120,496,2016 etc... as my result

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main(void) {
    for (int i = 2; i<100; i++)
    {
    bool prime = true;
    for (int j = 2; j*j <= i; j++)
    {
        if (pow(2,i) - 1 % j == 0)
        {
            prime = false;
            }
    }
    if (prime = true)
    {
        cout << pow(2, i - 1)*(pow(2, i) - 1) << " ";
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your if condition you have

```
if (prime = true)
```

the `=` operator is an assignment operator. This evaluates to `true` on every iteration in your case. You should be using the `==` operator. Instead you should have

```
if (prime == true)
```

Also, your inner `for` loop should run until the `sqrt` of `(pow(2, i) - 1)`. Right now you only test if numbers up to `i` are prime. Instead, make it

```
for (int j = 2; j*j <= pow(2,1)-1; j++)
```

Now, you iterate over all numbers until the square root of the desired value (the "right side" of Euler's theorem).

Sorry for all the edits and additions, but also: in your first `if` statement, I think the expression you have will not produce desired results, mainly because of order of operations. In C++, the `%` operand has higher precedence than +/-, so in the expression

```
pow(2,i) - 1 % j == 0
```

`1 % j` will be evaluated first, then the subtraction will be carried out. Again, this does not produce your desired results. The natural solution would be to simply place parentheses around the expression, like so:

```
(pow(2,i) - 1) % j == 0
```

But I think this might create some sort of "invalid operands" error, since the left side is of type `double` or `float`, and the right `int`. So just to be safe, I would cast it as an int:

```
(int)(pow(2,i) - 1) % j == 0
```